# работа с бинарными файлами, чтение и запись

Tags: c, файлы

Подскажите пожалуйста, Мне необходимо записать элементы массива (целые числа) в один бинарный файл, затем считать оттуда эти элементы, некоторые изменить и результат (вещественные числа) записать в другой бинарный файл. Открыл hex редактор, ответ вроде бы верный, но почему-то значение последнего элемента массива перескакивает в его начало. На фото правильный ответ **1.0 2.0 3.0 0.1**, а вот в файл записалось **0.1 1.0 2.0 3.0**, почему, как исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main() {
  int n, i, a[10];
  float b[10];
  FILE * f, * f2;
  f = fopen("probb1.dat", "rb+");
  do {
    printf("Enter n=");
    scanf("%i", & n);
  } while (n > 10);
  fwrite( & n, sizeof(int), 1, f);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("\a(%i)= ", i);
    scanf("%i", & a[i]);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%3i", a[i]);
    fwrite( & a[i], sizeof(int), 1, f);
  }
  fclose(f);
  f = fopen("probb1.dat", "rb+");
  f2 = fopen("probb2.dat", "wb+");
  fread( & n, sizeof(int), 1, f);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    fread( & a[i], sizeof(int), 1, f);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    b[i] = a[i];
    if (a[i] > 0) {
      if (a[i] % 4 == 0) {
        b[i] = 0.1;
      }
    }
  }
  fwrite( & n, sizeof(int), 1, f2);
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    fwrite( & b[j], sizeof(float), 1, f2);
  }
  printf("\n");
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    printf("%4.1f", b[j]);
  }
  fclose(f);
  fclose(f2);
  printf("\n");
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что файл `probb2.dat` неправильный? Тут все должно быть хорошо. Напишите маленькую программку, которая печатает его содержимое и убедитесь, что 0.1 это последнее число в нем. А вот тут `f = fopen("probb1.dat", "rb+");` у вас ошибка. Если файла еще нет, то программа упадет на первом `fwrite(&n, ..., f);`. Открывайте этот файл просто на запись -- `f = fopen("probb1.dat", "w");`

Comment: я сделал вывод исходя из содержимого двоичного файла, переконвертировал числа во float, и 0.1 вышло первым, хотя должно стоять в конце

Comment: Я думаю, вы смотрите в hex редакторе какой-то другой файл. По крайней мере первые 4 байта в `probb2.dat` д.б. `04 00 00 00` (это результат `fwrite( & n, sizeof(int), 1, f2);`)

Comment: Точно, моя невнимательность сыграла свою роль, а так все работает, спасибо!